# KeDei 3.5 SPI TFT LCD with Retropie

Tags: pi-3, retropie

I am working on an on the go Retro-pie system. I needed a screen to go onto it so I picked up a KeDei 3.5 inch TFT LCD. However when I received it, I found out that it only works with a specific image of raspbian. Where can i get the drivers for the 6.3 2016/11/1 model of the screen and how do I install them into retropie and allow for simultaneous use of the lcd and HDMI port.

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar KeDei 3.5 TFT LCD touchscreen using the SPI interface.

Regretfully, the device is NOT GOOD for Retropie due to very slow refresh rates.

There is a way to switch from LCD to HDMI, but required a reboot to switch.

As far as dual-monitor use, I had last looked into dual (or split) LCD and HDMI monitor use, but could not get that working. Long story short, I would not recommend wasting too much time on this LCD screen, it is mostly for static displays, not active gaming.

The SPI interface is a very slow framebuffer (fbtft) device.
The screen refresh rate across the SPI (serial peripheral interface) is too slow for retropie. It will result in "screen tearing" and choppy video, with a frame rate of about 2-3 per second. This is unacceptable for games.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have since gone to a laptop screen that runs at 60 htz. It might be overkill but eh... screw it

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not overly usable as the LCD is pretty slow. You can get the LCD to mirror what's on the HDMI output.

Install the LCD Show drivers from here: http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html

Be sure and reboot, then download: https://github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp  . Change output framebuffer device to be /dev/fb0 by changing line 41 of main.c in rpi-fbcp. Build and run as per the Readme.md and Emulationstation will be on the LCD too.